# Probability with Independent Normal Variables

Tags: statistics

Let X and Y be independent standard normal variables. Find:

a) P(3X + 2Y > 5)

Comment: I see you haven't accepted any of the answers to your previous questions -- did they not answer your questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some hints that should go a long way towards answers.

(a) In your course, you may have learned that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal with means $p$, $q$ and variances $s^2$, $t^2$, then $aX+bY$ is normal mean $ap+bq$, variance $a^2s^2+b^2t^2$.  So $3X+2Y$ has mean $0$, variance $13$.

(b)  Our probability is $1$ minus the probability that they are *both* $\ge 1$. What is the probability that $X \ge 1$?

(c)  The probability that the absolute value of $\min(X,Y)$ is less than $1$ is the probability that $(X < 1) \cup (Y<1)$ minus the probability that  $(X \le -1) \cup (Y \le -1)$.

(d) This is the probability that $|X-Y|<1$.  Let $W=X-Y$ and look at the remark for part (a).

Comment: The hint on part (a) is false: standard gaussian random variables have mean $0$ and variance $1$ hence $3X+2Y$ has mean $0$ and variance $13$, and one very much needs to know the variance. The hint on part (c) is false as well: if $X=10$ and $Y=0$, $|\min(X,Y)|=0$ but $X$ does not lie between $-1$ and $1$. (And already three upvotes... :-))

Comment: @Didier Pau: I thank you for pointing out the errors. There was further discussion in another post, where I corrected (a). Is there a way of removing the upvotes?

Comment: You are welcome. Please do not worry about upvotes (or downvotes, for that matter), they mean next to nothing.

Comment: But you definitely should correct your answer (why you do not is beyond me).

Comment: @Didier Piau: I had corrected once, completely, but it did not take. Maybe I forgot to save.  I am not satisfied with my hint in (c), it is less intuitively clear than the others.